# JavaScript update Object value from another object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have two objects, one is used to update the other, something like ETL Process.

```
const currentObject = {
    myObject : [
      {
        'attribute1':'foo1',
        'attribute2':'bar1',
        'attribute3':'test1'
      },
      {
        'attribute1':'foo2',
        'attribute2':'bar2',
        'attribute3':'test2'
      },
      {
       'attribute1':'foo3',
       'attribute2':'bar3',
       'attribute3':'test3'
      },
   ]
}
```

if the attribute3 value is "test1", then go to the other object and check for the test1 property and replace the currentObject with the new value

```
const updateObject = {
  myObject : {
    'test1':'newtest1',
    'test2':'newtest2',
    'test3':'newtest3'
  }
}
```

update is done on currentObject attribute3 needs to use updateObject property as reference;
where currentObject attribute1="test1" should copy data from updateObject test1 so on:

Final value should be like:

```
const currentObject = {
    myObject : [
      {
        'attribute1':'foo1',
        'attribute2':'bar1',
        'attribute3':'newtest1'
      },
      {
        'attribute1':'foo2',
        'attribute2':'bar2',
        'attribute3':'newtest2'
      },
      {
       'attribute1':'foo3',
       'attribute2':'bar3',
       'attribute3':'newtest3'
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code snippet where you tried to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` and `Object.entries`

Here idea is

- First loop through each element in `myObject` array of `currentObject`
- Now as in your structure you have value of `currentObject` as `key` in `updateObject`, so we check existence by `updateObject.myObject[value]`
- If it's their we update `currentObject` else we keep it unchanged

```js
const currentObject = {myObject : [{'attribute1':'foo1','attribute2':'bar1','attribute3':'test1'},{'attribute1':'foo2','attribute2':'bar2','attribute3':'test2'},{'attribute1':'foo3','attribute2':'bar3','attribute3':'test3'},]}
const updateObject = {myObject : {'test1':'newtest1','test2':'newtest2','test3':'newtest3'}}

currentObject.myObject.forEach(e => {

Object.entries(e).forEach(([key,value]) => {
    if(updateObject.myObject[value]){
      e[key] = updateObject.myObject[value]
    }
  })
})

console.log(currentObject)
```

Comment: It took me sometime to fully understand the logic and end up with doubt, what if I wanted to change the "e[key]" to update the value for another attribute in the currentObject, can it be done only by updating this line of code? e[key] = updateObject.myObject[value], thanks for the code this is good logic to improve my skills.

Comment: @bernlt yes you should change that line accordingly if you want to achieve anything else than you specified in question

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Array.reduce` and search for the current element's (`ele`) `attribute3` property in the `updateObject.myObject`.

If present then update it with the matching value from the `updateObject.myObject` else keep the old one :

```js
const currentObject = {myObject : [{'attribute1':'foo1','attribute2':'bar1','attribute3':'test1'},{'attribute1':'foo2','attribute2':'bar2','attribute3':'test2'},{'attribute1':'foo3','attribute2':'bar3','attribute3':'test3'},]};
const updateObject = {myObject : {'test1':'newtest1','test2':'newtest2','test3':'newtest3'}};

function transformObject(currentObject, updateObject){
    const out = currentObject.myObject.reduce((acc, ele) => {
       ele.attribute3 = updateObject.myObject[ele.attribute3] ?
                        updateObject.myObject[ele.attribute3] : 
                        ele.attribute3;
       return acc.concat(ele);
    }, []);
    finalObj = {[Object.keys(currentObject)[0]] : out };
    return finalObj;
}
console.log(transformObject(currentObject, updateObject));
```

Comment: Hey this is great, can you help me understand this line of code: finalObj = {[Object.keys(currentObject)[0]] : out };

Comment: @bernlt actually that is adding the `myObject` key in the `finalObj`  output. so `Object.keys` will return the array of keys in the `currentObject` which will be `[myObject]` but I want the string value so I need to take the '0'th index from the array.

Answer (score 1):

This turns into a one-liner with the latest JavaScript language features:

```js
const currentObject = {
  myObject: [
    {
      'attribute1': 'foo1',
      'attribute2': 'bar1',
      'attribute3': 'test1'
    },
    {
      'attribute1': 'foo2',
      'attribute2': 'bar2',
      'attribute3': 'test2'
    },
    {
      'attribute1': 'foo3',
      'attribute2': 'bar3',
      'attribute3': 'test3'
    },
  ]
}

const updateObject = {
  myObject: {
    'test1': 'newtest1',
    'test2': 'newtest2',
    'test3': 'newtest3'
  }
}

const result = { myObject: currentObject.myObject.map(o => ({ ...o, ...{ 'attribute3': updateObject.myObject[o.attribute3] } })) };

console.log(result);
```

...and you also get immutability.